# What is the time complexity of these for loops

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity

I got two for loops

```
for(int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++){
    for(int j = 2 * i; j <= n; j++){
    }
}
```

What is the time complexity of them? My idea is that the total number of the iteration would be (n - 4) + (n - 6) + (n - 8) + .... + 4 + 2 + 1. Is that mean the time complexity is O(n)? Thank you

What if I change j++ to j += i? How to calculate the number of iterations?

Comment: No, it simplifies to O(n*n) because for each of the n / 2 outer loops you have n (n minus constant simplifies to n) inner loops. This type of question is not very appropriate for StackOverflow, and seems more apropriate for some of the other StackExchange sites like http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Still O(n*n) because n multiplied by a constant simplifies to n (`j += i` is constant in the inner loop). Might be easier to visualize if you calculate the number of loops for some values of n, and draw them on a x-y axis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: Thanks Slai. I am still a little confused. My idea is the iteration would be n / 2 + (n - 3) / 3 + (n - 4) / 4 + (n - 5) / 5 + ....  + (n - (n - 1)) / (n - 1), is that would be O(n * n)? I thought it might be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Overall TC should be `O(N^2)`.

`O(N)` for outer and `O(N)` of inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed methodically, using Sigma notation:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. Time complexity is O(n)